# Is z-score meaningful in classification or regression?

Tags: classification, z-statistic

I am a beginner in statistics, therefore I hope I can state my problem in a correct manner. I have a some instances or samples and I can collect below statistical parameters for **classification and regression** problem:

- Sample Size
- Minimum value
- Maximum value
- Standard deviation
- Variance
- Mean

And, I want to use **z-scores** to compare or classify samples, my question is: does using z-score **make sense** or what can I use instead of z-score to obtain meaningful classification parameter?

Comment: Can't you collect the mean? You're not going to be able to calculate a $z$-score without it.

Comment: @onestop I can collect mean, also editing question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform linear regression you'd need not only the means and variances of the variables but also all their covariances (or equivalently their correlations).

If you can collect the means, variances and covariances/correlations separately in each of the classes you wish to classify, you can do [linear discriminant analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis), which is a classification method, albeit a somewhat old-fashioned one with some rather restrictive normality assumptions.

Comment: if I provide z-scores, correlations can be determined by 3rd party tools like WEKA, am I right?

Comment: I mean, attribute selection or information gain calculations are enough to keep some z-scores and remove unnecessary ones, aren`t they?

Comment: You've lost me completely there, I'm afraid. Others may understand what you're talking about, but it must be outside my field.

Comment: Many apologies, @baris_a, I've deleted my comment that replied "no" to your first comment above as I've just realised the answer is in fact "yes", i.e. you *can* compute correlations from $z$-scores. Truly sorry, I must have been having a brainstorm earlier. I still don't know what 'attribute selection' or 'information gain calculations' are though, I'm afraid.

Comment: @onestop I am not sure I understand what you say when you write that it works under a "rather restrictive normality assumption". What do you mean by that ? I found very general the idea of projecting a "new" observation on the centroid difference after normalizing everything with the covariance geometry don't you ?